# MDX query for PPS Report

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Let me preface by saying this is my first foray into PPS and MDX, so I'm quite boneheaded at the moment.  I hope someone can help me out as I can't seem to figure it out with the google.

I have created an Analytic Chart in PPS and deployed to SP 2010.  I'd like to pass in values from a SP List filter to the chart.  My MDX looks like:

**SELECT { [Measures].[MyMeasures] }
ON COLUMNS,
{ [MyDim].[MyDimId].[MyDimId].ALLMEMBERS }
ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube]
WHERE ( [OtherDim].[OtherDimId].[`<<Parameter>>`] )**

I'm hoping someone can get me started on using conditional logic based on the passed in `<<Parameter>>` (the double angle brackets is PPS syntax).

Basically, if the SP List filter connected to the report looks like:

(Empty)

Value1

Value2

This will work as is for Value1 and Value2, but I need some way to check if `<<Parameter>>` is (Empty).  If so, I would set it to ALLMEMBERS, or even just eliminate the entire WHERE clause.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your MDX to end with `WHERE (<<Parameter>>)` which will mean a blank parameter creates `WHERE()` and will have no effect. You'll need to pass the full OtherDim member name within the parameter though.